# Zoom MKMapView to fit polyline and annotation pins - Horizontal orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkpolyline, mkmapcamera

I have an iOS app with a view that contains a few different labels plus a small MKMapView.

On the map view, I have draw a trip route (using a polyline) and have added two annotation pins, one at the start of the route and the other at the end of the route.

All I am trying to do is to change the map zoom/rotation, so that the polyline and two annotation pins, fit the size of the map view. However everything I have tried has failed.

**My approach**

1) Add the polyline to the map view.

2) Use `setVisibleMapRect` to adjust the map view, so that the polyline fits within the map. (I have also added some padding, by using the edge insets parameter).

3) Use `MKMapCamera` to change the rotation of the map, so that the polyline + pins are presented in a horizontal manner.

Here is my code:

```
// Convert the preview string to a
// MKPolyline map direction object.
MKPolyline *map_data = [self polyline_with_encoded_string:[trip preview]];

// Add the polyline to the map view.
[main_map addOverlay:map_data];

// Set the display area around the polyline.
[main_map setVisibleMapRect:[map_data boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(28.0, 28.0, 28.0, 28.0) animated:YES];

// Calculate the current clockwise degree.
double degree = [self calculate_bearing_angle:[trip.startPoint latitude] :[trip.startPoint longitude] :[trip.stopPoint latitude] :[trip.stopPoint longitude]];

// Change the degree to the approriate
// trip polyline degree (anti-clockwise).

if ((degree >= 0) && (degree <= 90)) {
    degree = (270 + degree);
}

else if ((degree > 90) && (degree <= 180)) {
    degree = (270 - (degree - 90));
}

else if ((degree > 180) && (degree <= 270)) {
    degree = (360 - (degree - 180));
}

else if ((degree > 270) && (degree <= 360)) {
    degree = (90 + degree);
}

// Rotate the map so that the trip polyline
// fits horizontally rather than vertically.
MKMapCamera *map_camera = [[main_map camera] copy];
[map_camera setHeading:degree];
[main_map setCamera:map_camera animated:YES];
```

I am using the following method to figure out the angle of the polyline:

```
-(double)calculate_bearing_angle:(double)start_lat :(double)start_lon :(double)end_lat :(double)end_lon {

    // Get the seperate latitude/longitude values.
    double from_lat = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(start_lat);
    double from_lon = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(start_lon);
    double to_lat = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(end_lat);
    double to_lon = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(end_lon);

    // Calculate the bearing angle.
    double degree = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(sin(to_lon - from_lon) * cos(to_lat), cos(from_lat) * sin(to_lat) - sin(from_lat) * cos(to_lat) * cos(to_lon - from_lon)));

    if (degree >= 0) {
        return degree;
    }

    else {
        return (360 + degree);
    }
}
```

I have tried everything, but either way the end result is that certain polylines at certain angles are rotated to the correct horizontal angle and others arn't.... what an earth am I doing wrong? Or is there a better built in approach to this problem?

All I want to do, is to change this:

[image]

... to this:

[image]

Comment: why you pass a latitude to DEGREES_TO_RADIANS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been working in your problem, for me this method `[[self.map camera] setHeading:90.f];` works as intended, so maybe your problem is in the calculation on radians and the latter process, but maybe your problem is also related to the copy of camera. I use this method directly on the map´s camera and works great. I hope this helps you

Comment: I know that code works, my problem is in recalculating the appropriate degree that the map should be rotated too.

Comment: Ahh ok @Supertecnoboff I will research further, if I found something helpful I will post as update